# Summing an instance up per key? Dictionary? Write to CSV?

Tags: python, csv

I want to be able to sum how many times a 5 star rank showed up per the week index.  How would I do so?  I want to do this for all of the ranks from 1 to 5. The data is in a 2d array.

For example, Week Index 4_2015 would be (4) rank 5's. Is there a library to do such a thing?

The data structure is an array as follows:

```
[[5, 4_2015], [5, 4_2015], [1,9_2015] ... ]
```

Using the counter I have:

```
 Counter({('5', '10_2015'): 197, ('5', '9_2015'): 134, ('5', '4_2015'): 122,      
 ('5', '5_2015'): 114, ('5', '11_2015'): 97, ('5', '48_2014'): 83, ('5', 
 '3_2015'): 64, ('5', '51_2014'): 57, ('5', '8_2015'): 49, ('5', '15_2015'): 
 45, ('5', '46_2014'): 40, ('5', '13_2015'): 39, ('5', '49_2014'): 35, ('5', 
'47_2014'): 27, ('5', '12_2015'): 26, ('1', '9_2014'): 24})
```

However when I try to write it to a CSV I just get the week index number and the value, but I want to write with the rank, the week index and the number of instances observed.

Comment: Please provide the actual data structure you're working with rather than a pretty-printed representation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use collections.Counter by generating a list of tuples from your lists of lists, e.g. assuming the list of lists is in `data`:

```
from collections import Counter
c = Counter((rank, week) for rank, week in data)
print(c[(5, '4_2015')])
```

Would print out the number of rank 5s for the week '4_2015'.